# openlayers-angular: custom control in ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent div. How?

Tags: angular, openlayers, sidebar

- package.json: "ol": "^6.5.0"
- angular.json: styles property: "node_modules/ol/ol.css",

I have an angular component(project-info-sidebar) rendering the [umbe1987sidebar](https://github.com/umbe1987/sidebar-v2/blob/ol5-sidebar/js/ol5-sidebar.js).

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, TemplateRef, AfterViewInit, Inject, InjectionToken } from "@angular/core";
import Sidebar from "../../../js/ol5-sidebar.js";
import { TemplateserviceService } from 'src/app/services/templateservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: './project-info-sidebar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-info-sidebar.component.scss'],
})
export class ProjectInfoSidebarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("sidebar") mySidebarDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  sidebar: Sidebar | null = null;

  childTemplate?: any;

  constructor(private templateService: TemplateserviceService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const element = this.mySidebarDiv.nativeElement;
    this.childTemplate = element;
    this.templateService.setTemplate(this.childTemplate)
  }
}
```

Another component (project-info-map) subscribed to templateService:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { openlayersMap } from '../openlayers-map';
import { TemplateserviceService } from 'src/app/services/templateservice.service';
import Sidebar from "../../../js/ol5-sidebar.js";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-project-info-map',
  templateUrl: './project-info-map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./project-info-map.component.scss']
})
export class ProjectInfoMapComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  mimapa: openlayersMap;
  childTemplate?: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

  sidebar: Sidebar | null = null;

  constructor(private templateService: TemplateserviceService) {
    this.templateService.template$.subscribe(t => this.childTemplate = t);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sidebar = new Sidebar({
      element: this.childTemplate
    });
    this.mimapa = new openlayersMap('mapcanvas');
    this.mimapa.map.addControl(this.sidebar);
    this.sidebar.setMap(this.mimapa.map);
  }
}
```

The sidebar is rendered faded, pale.
No alerts in console. No errors.

Becasue is faded, I cannot click on sidebar icons and test open method per example.

According to ol api, by default Controls are placed in the container with CSS class name `ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent` (within div with ol-viewport CSS class).

The problem is that this custom control is not within that div. Instead:

```html
<app-project-info>
    <div _ngcontent-ojf-c93 class= projectinfo>
        <app-project-info-map>
            <div _ngcontent-ojf-c92="" id="mapcanvas" class="mapcanvas">
            <sidebar _ngcontent-ojf-c92="" _nghost-ojf-c91="">...</sidebar>
            <div class="ol-viewport" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
                <div class="ol-unselectable ol-layers" style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 0;">
                </div>
                <div class="ol-overlaycontainer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
                </div>
                <div class="ol-overlaycontainer-stopevent" style="position: absolute; z-index: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; pointer-events: none;">
                    <div class="ol-overviewmap ol-custom-overviewmap ol-unselectable ol-control ol-collapsed" style="pointer-events: auto;">..</div>
                    <div class="ol-attribution ol-unselectable ol-control ol-uncollapsible" style="pointer-events: auto;">...</div>
                    <div class="ol-zoom ol-unselectable ol-control" style="pointer-events: auto;">...</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </app-project-info-map>
    </div>
</app-project-info>
```

Another problem is when I access the collecttion of Controls under `map.getControls()`.

Altough I see the sidebar custom control in the array, I notice the prop map for this control is `null`, whereas the others have Map {...}:

```s
Collection {disposed: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, …}
array_: Array(4)
0: OverviewMap {disposed: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: null, dispatching_: null, listeners_: null, …}
1: Attribution {disposed: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: null, dispatching_: null, listeners_: null, …}
2: Zoom
    dispatching_: null
    disposed: false
    duration_: 250
    element: div.ol-zoom.ol-unselectable.ol-control
    eventTarget_: undefined
    listenerKeys: [{…}]
    listeners_: null
    map_: Map {disposed: false, eventTarget_: undefined, pendingRemovals_: {…}, dispatching_: {…}, listeners_: {…}, …}
    ol_uid: "19"
    pendingRemovals_: null
    revision_: 0
    target_: null
    values_: null
__proto__: Control
3: Sidebar
    dispatching_: null
    disposed: false
    element: div.sidebar-left
    eventTarget_: undefined
    listenerKeys: []
    listeners_: null
    map_: null
    ol_uid: "37"
    pendingRemovals_: null
    revision_: 0
    target_: null
    values_: null
_closeButtons: (4) [span.sidebar-close, span.sidebar-close, span.sidebar-close, span.sidebar-close]
_container: div.sidebar-content
_panes: (4) [div#settings.sidebar-pane, div#messages.sidebar-pane, div#profile.sidebar-pane, div#home.sidebar-pane]
_tabitems: NodeList(5) [li, li, li.disabled, li, li]
__proto__: Control
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I tought that was covered when doing `this.sidebar.setMap(this.mimapa.map)`, because I see how the map is set to the control in https://github.com/umbe1987/sidebar-v2/blob/ol5-sidebar/js/ol5-sidebar.js when debugging.

How to make sidebar custom control to behave as a normal control in Angular?

Comment: It looks like sidebar is based on ol v.5. This may be the source of the issue.

Comment: I was missing the class="sidebar collapsed" attribute in the #sidebar dom node... at some point I deleted I believe. It works for v.6 quite well!